# relation between one variable nominal and other ordinal

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, ordinal-data

What is the best way to know the relation between two variables like gender (MAN/WOMAN) and opinion (Very Bad, Bad, Neutral, Good, Very good).

(Nominal with ordinal)

I think that with a chiq-square you can know if they are dependent, but if they are, how can you know the type of this relation? and try to explain it for example with a Contingenc Cofficient, Spearman Corration etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) to compare the mean rank of female answers with the mean rank of males answers.